# Setting localhost certificate to be iis express development certificate

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I understand I can use IIS to set the certificate for the website running on localhost to
IIS Express Development Certificate...

But how would I do this programmatically using a c# and .net program running on the individuals machine?

Or even using powershell.. or a cmd script.. just in a programmatic way that can be executed

Comment: You can use Powershell: `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "myapp1, myapp2, myapp3" -FriendlyName "My Local Certificates" -NotAfter (get-date).AddYears(5)`. Open the certificate manager and move this new certificate from the intermediate store to the trusted store and add it to your binding

Answer (score 0):

Tim Buntrock posted an article on 4sysOps to run one locally for SQL Server.  The self-signing concept should be the same.

```
https://4sysops.com/archives/create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-powershell/#:~:text=Tim%20Buntrock%20is%20one%20of%20three%20enterprise%20administrators,certificate%20you%20sign%20with%20your%20own%20private%20key.
```

Answer (score 0):

`netsh` is the simplest command line you can use to associate certificates to ports and DNS names (SNI),

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate

You can also consume Windows HTTP API in C#, or use `IISAdministration` PowerShell cmdlets. Examples can be found via search engines.